# Server Error from a classic mailing script

Tags: perl, email

I am using a standard classic Perl mail processing script that used to work on previous server but now returns "500 Server Error". I don't see a reason for that... where could be issue?
Here are the script settings:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -wT
##############################################################################
# nms Formmail                         Version 3.14c1                        #
# Copyright 2001 London Perl Mongers   All rights reserved                   #
# Created 11/11/01                     Last Modified 08/11/04                #
# Matt's Script Archive:               http://www.scriptarchive.com/         #
##############################################################################
#
# NMS FormMail Version 3.14c1
#

use strict;
use vars qw(
  $DEBUGGING $emulate_matts_code $secure %more_config
  $allow_empty_ref $max_recipients $mailprog @referers
  @allow_mail_to @recipients %recipient_alias
  @valid_ENV $date_fmt $style $send_confirmation_mail
  $confirmation_text $locale $charset $no_content
  $double_spacing $wrap_text $wrap_style $postmaster 
  $address_style
);

# PROGRAM INFORMATION
# -------------------
# FormMail.pl Version 3.14c1

# USER CONFIGURATION SECTION
# --------------------------
# Modify these to your own settings.

BEGIN
{
  $DEBUGGING         = 0;
  $emulate_matts_code= 0;
  $secure            = 1;
  $allow_empty_ref   = 0;
  $max_recipients    = 1;
  $mailprog          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t';
  $postmaster        = '';
  @referers          = qw(reverd.com localhost);
  @allow_mail_to     = qw(stavam@lightspeed.ca);
  @recipients        = ();
  %recipient_alias   = ('9' => 'stavam@lightspeed.ca');
  @valid_ENV         = qw(REMOTE_HOST REMOTE_ADDR REMOTE_USER HTTP_USER_AGENT);
  $locale            = '';
  $charset           = 'iso-8859-1';
  $date_fmt          = '%A, %B %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S';
  $style             = 'https://reverd.com/css/reverd.css';
  $no_content        = 0;
  $double_spacing    = 0;
  $wrap_text         = 0;
  $wrap_style        = 1;
  $address_style     = 0;
  $send_confirmation_mail = 1;
  $confirmation_text = <<'END_OF_CONFIRMATION';
From: noreply@reverd.com
Subject: Your reverd.com contact submission

Hi,
Thank you for contacting Reverd!
We will try to respond within 24 hours.

Thank you!
https://reverd.com - get rid of scam calls automatically


END_OF_CONFIRMATION

# You may need to uncomment the line below and adjust the path.
# use lib './lib';

# USER CUSTOMISATION SECTION
# --------------------------
# Place any custom code here


# USER CUSTOMISATION << END >>
# ----------------------------
# (no user serviceable parts beyond here)
}
```

and the Contact us form - [Contact us][1]
[1]: https://reverd.com/about/contact

Like I said it used to work smoothly on the previous server as it is and suddenly after moving to a new server it keeps returning "500 Server Error". I hope that all the setting are correct. I was using Matt's Form mail for many websites with no issues... wonder what is causing this 500 Server Error...

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. for more information, see the logfiles

Comment: Did you inspect your error logs? From what I can tell the problem is not with the mail script but with the contact page.

Comment: `500 Server Error` is from the web server. You need to provide the error from the script.

Comment: The spaces before the `#!` are definitely a problem if they're there in the actual file. The `#!` needs to be the very first two bytes of the file.

Comment: So the actual code that you run is something other than this settings file? There is no code here, just settings. Are you running FormMail.pl? There is not enough information here to say anything useful, we don't even know your OS or webserver, or what code you ran to get the 500 error.

Comment: Problem solved. Classic script abandoned and replaced with a newer one. All good now. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @user22105603: *Classic script abandoned and replaced with a newer one* - well, I told you how to get the original program working. But, sure, throw it away and start again from scratch :-)

Comment: @user22105603: Also, in order for this question to be useful to anyone else with similar problems, it would be great if you could add an answer explaining exactly what you did - e.g. which program you switched to.

Answer (score 2):

I was a member of the team that wrote nms Formmail. To be honest, I'm kinda surprised to see someone still using it. As others say, we'd need to see what the actual error message is (from the web server's error log).

But, if I had to guess, I'd say that it was because your new server is running a newer version of Perl - one that doesn't include CGI.pm as part of the standard installation.

That's just a guess though. I can't be sure until I see the real error message.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your comment (nice to hear from the creators). You are correct: there is no such thing as CGI.pm on my new server... Do you know some newer reliable Perl script that can handle emails? Thx.

Comment: @user22105603: People stopped writing formmail programs a lifetime ago. The nms formmail is still reliable - you just need to install CGI.pm. Ask the sysadmin to do it for you. Or put a Google Form on your site instead.